# Why don't some sample candidate profiles have a default gravatar in them?

Tags: support, jobs, gravatar

I was playing around in [Careers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow_%28website%29#Careers) and found the [employers search page for candidates](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/search).

Clicking around on sample profiles, I noticed most have the default gravatar picture, but some don't have that default gravatar, leaving just a blank space there.

Example for a candidate with a default gravatar:

> [image]

And a gravatarless profile:

> [image]

Does this have any meaning? Or is it just me being too nitpicking?

Comment: I suspect that the *normal* profile photo has been replaced by a uniform anonymous picture. The other profile has no photo itself, so it didn't need anonymizing either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how can profile have no photo? Have you ever seen such profile?

Comment: There is a checkbox on the profile edit form to not show your gravatar.

Comment: @MartijnPieters cool, totally missed that! Pretty sure that's the case indeed, feel free to post this as answer.

Comment: @Peter thanks, guess I'll never get my head around these things!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample profiles are real profiles, anonymized. In the process, real gravatar images are replaced by the anonymous person silhouette.

However, not all profiles *have* a gravatar, you can switch off the display of the image:

[image: display gravatar switch]

Presumably, the profile with no profile picture is one that has that option unchecked.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks! FHRC is not complete but I forgive you... ;)

Comment: Let's not start the FHRC-completeness holy wars all over again! They were worse than the red vs green wars we just managed to bring to a stalemate...

Comment: If you're not 100% sure: what does clicking that "what is this?" link to?

Comment: It links to the gravatar website explaining what a gravatar is.